# Sql replace vowels in a string if that string exists in another table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table which contains specific words.

[image]

Now when I insert a new post I want to replace the vowels in the strings that the word table contains before it is being inserted. So that's why I need to use a trigger function with instead of insert.
I got this so far:

```
Create TRIGGER trChangeAbusiveWord
ON Post
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN

Declare @abusiveWord nvarchar(max)
Declare @correctedWord nvarchar(max)

Select @abusiveWord = b.Woord FROM Scheldwoorden b WHERE exists 
    (select Message FROM inserted a where a.Message like '%' + b.Woord + '%')


Select @correctedWord = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@abusiveWord, 'A', '*'), 'E', '*'), 'O', '*'), 'U', '*'), 'I', '*')

Select Replace(Message, @abusiveWord, @correctedWord) FROM Message b
When done changed words, insert query here.

END
```

Now when I insert this message:

```
INSERT into Post(Id_User, Id_Topic, Titel, Message) VALUES (7,1, 'TriggerMe', 'Hi im bear and I want to cook a nice meal')
```

I want to change the message to 'Hi im b--r and I want to c--k a nice m--l'

But with what the queries I got so far, it only changes the first word like this:

'Hi im b**r and I want to cook a nice meal'

Comment: If I have understood it right, this is what you are trying.
1. **Scheldwoorden** is a table that has the list of specific words.
2. **inserted** is the table which contains the whole string _"Hi im bear and I want to cook a nice meal"_
So here the below select query only returns one record to the Variable **@abusiveWord**
`Select @abusiveWord = b.Woord FROM Scheldwoorden b WHERE exists`
`(select Inhoud FROM inserted a where a.Inhoud like '%' + b.Woord + '%')`

Thus it only replaces the word _Bear_ as it gets stored into the variable.

Comment: @Joby Yes that's correct but I can't get it to work with multiple words

Comment: String manipulation really isn't SQL's forte - I suspect this would be easier done in code.

Comment: You could do something funky with xml.path commands - eg split the string into a #table of words using SPACE as the delimiter, do an UPDATE on the #table by joining to your Scheldwoorden table, then concatenate the #table back into a string with a FOR XML loop.  This would be hideous, and Reeeeaaaaly slow... but would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do and update on the table which contains the word and set the actual string by replacing vowels from all the words in the table.

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100) = 'Hi im bear and I want to cook a nice meal'

DECLARE @AbusiveWords TABLE(ID INT,Word VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @AbusiveWords (ID,Word) values (1,'bear'),(2,'cook'),(3,'meal')

UPDATE @AbusiveWords
SET @String=REPLACE(@String,Word,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Word,'A','-'),'E','-'),'I','-'),'O','-'),'U','-')) 
PRINT(@string);
```

**Output:**

```
Hi im b--r and I want to c--k a nice m--l
```

Comment: This helped me alot with some minor modifications I got what I wanted !

Answer (score 0):

Use REPLACE built in function :

```
  DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100) = 'Hi im bear and I want to cook a nice meal'

  SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@String,'A','-
            '),'E','-'),'I','-'),'O','-'),'U','-')
```

Use below query for String replace only on given values :

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100) = 'Hi im bear and I want to cook a nice meal'

DECLARE @Word1 VARCHAR(100) = 'bear'
DECLARE @Word2 VARCHAR(100) = 'meal'
DECLARE @Word3 VARCHAR(100) = 'cook'

DECLARE @ReplaceWord1 VARCHAR(100) = ''
DECLARE @ReplaceWord2 VARCHAR(100) = ''
DECLARE @ReplaceWord3 VARCHAR(100) = ''

SELECT @ReplaceWord1 = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@Word1, 'A', 
       '*'), 'E', '*'), 'O', '*'), 'U', '*'), 'I', '*')
SELECT @ReplaceWord2 = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@Word2, 'A', 
       '*'), 'E', '*'), 'O', '*'), 'U', '*'), 'I', '*')
SELECT @ReplaceWord3 = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@Word3, 'A', 
       '*'), 'E', '*'), 'O', '*'), 'U', '*'), 'I', '*')

SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@String, @Word1, @ReplaceWord1), @Word2, 
       @ReplaceWord2), @Word3, @ReplaceWord3)
```

For replace multiple words :

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100) = 'Hi im bear and I want to cook a nice meal'

DECLARE @ReplaceWords TABLE ( OrgWord VARCHAR(100) , ReplaceWord 
       VARCHAR(100) , Flag TINYINT DEFAULT(0) )
DECLARE @OrgWord VARCHAR(100) = ''
DECLARE @ReplaceWord VARCHAR(100) = ''

INSERT INTO @ReplaceWords ( OrgWord )
SELECT 'bear' UNION ALL
SELECT 'meal' UNION ALL
SELECT 'cook' 

UPDATE @ReplaceWords SET ReplaceWord = 
       REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(OrgWord, 'A', '*'), 'E', 
       '*'), 'O', '*'), 'U', '*'), 'I', '*')

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @ReplaceWords WHERE Flag = 0)
BEGIN

    SELECT TOP 1 @OrgWord = OrgWord , @ReplaceWord = ReplaceWord 
    FROM @ReplaceWords WHERE Flag = 0

    SET @String = REPLACE(@String, @OrgWord, @ReplaceWord)

   UPDATE @ReplaceWords SET Flag = 1 WHERE OrgWord = @OrgWord

 END

 SELECT @String
```

Comment: This changes all the vowels of the whole sentence, not only the words that matches with the words in the other table

Comment: @Jeffreydww,what kind of words other table having.Specify any sample

Comment: Alright so like in the example I have the message 'Hi im bear and I want to cook a meal' Now in the other table I got the words bear, meal and cook. So in the sentence I want to change the vowels in these specific words only. the word bear has to become b--r then we also have the word cook in that table list so that word has to become c--k and when al the matched words are changed I want to get the sentence: 'Hi im b--r and I want to c--k a m--l'

Comment: @Jeffreydww,I updated my answer based on your commands.Check it now.

Comment: @Mansoor This will work but what if the table has 100 records, you will use 200 variables?? With this code for each new word added to the table, you will have to alter your query.

Comment: @JibinBalachandran,I simplify my query for multiple words in that table.